# PartialView is returning fullpage, only rendering the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to rerender the partialview ONLY in my modal, after the ajax request.
But when I get the response everything is rerendered and the only thing showing is the partialview..

PartialView:

```
@{
    var bidModel = new BidModel();
}

<div>
    <div class="row">
        @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success">@ViewBag.Message</div>
        }
    </div>
    <span class=" alert-danger">
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
    </span>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="Bidder" asp-for="@bidModel.Bidder" value="@User.Identity.Name" type="hidden" />
        <input name="AuctionId" asp-for="@bidModel.AuctionId" type="hidden" id="auctionId" />
        <label asp-for="@bidModel.Amount" />
        <input name="Amount" asp-for="@bidModel.Amount" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddBid(BidModel Bid)
    {
        var result = await _bidBusinessInterface.CreateBidAsync(Bid, Bid.AuctionId);
        if (result)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Bud lagt!";

        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Bud förlågt!";
        }
        return PartialView("_BidCreatorPartial");
    }
```

And then we have the modal where i want to rerender the partialview:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="bidModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bidModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="bidModalLabel">Lägg bud</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form asp-action="AddBid" asp-controller="Home" method="POST" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="frmBid">
                                <div id="frmBid">
                                    <partial name="_BidCreatorPartial" model="@bidModel"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Avbryt</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Spara</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As I said, what I want to accomplish is to rerender the form, so that the message can be shown in the modal.

What happens is it renders a whole white page with only the form and the message.

Comment: You need to set the layout to `null` via `@{ Layout = null; }`

Comment: And btw. partial views are meant for reusability, not for async loading via ajax

Comment: What do you mean? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually post your form itself, but my best guess is that you're just doing a standard old HTML form post. That's *always* going to cause the page to change, and then since you're only returning a partial view, and not a full view, your page gets replaced with just that snippet of HTML.

What you want requires AJAX. You need to catch the submit event on the form, and instead of letting it go as normal, you make an AJAX request with the form data serialized. Then, in the success callback of your AJAX request, you'll need to query the element you want to replace the HTML of from the DOM and change its `innerHTML` value to what's returned from the AJAX request.

Since an ASP.NET Core project comes with jQuery out of the box, I'm going to assume you can use that:

```
$('#MyForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        method: 'post',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function (html) {
            $('#frmBid').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a question, what do I return in the controller? Because it says it will never enter the success function